# Swift 5 replacingOccurrences multiple elements

Tags: swift

```
let osetx = "01et"
```

I want to replace "e" with "11" and "t" with "10." What is the syntax to do that by calling the function only once?

```
let newOsetx = osetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "11")
```

The above only replaces one of the 2 elements, obviously.

THANK YOU pawello2222 for the syntax in the comments.

osetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "11").replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "10")

Comment: What's the fear of calling `replacingOccurrences` twice?

Comment: Sorry, newbie here, but if I call the function twice, don't I have to declare a new name for the string each time? If yes, that's my "fear" (just seems bloated). And I can't figure out the syntax to use a For loop on replacingOccurences.

Comment: osetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "11").replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "10")

Comment: @George it can be slow (I identified a bottleneck with chaining it via profiling)

Comment: @aehlke Hmm. Two of them is the same time complexity as having one of them. Though, it seems memory is copied for both which can be expensive. Either make sure you’re in release mode, or maybe make a custom loop to do this. Unless this is a string with a million characters or called extremely frequently, I wouldn’t bother optimising such a small part—it’ll have little effect across the whole program.

Comment: It's not necessarily a small part, it was the bottleneck in my case due to being called repeatedly across a series of large texts. I replaced them with a regex. But always just use profiling to determine bottlenecks (this was one for me - one user action spent 3-5 seconds across CPU cores inside of my chained replacingOccurrences) and whether changes improve it of course. Btw time complexity is taught in CS and tested a lot at jobs but is not always useful in optimization especially when considering things like cache locality and user expectations (where 0.5s vs 5s can have same complexity)

Comment: @George one more example - if you call a web API in a loop, it may technically be an O(n) operation, but with 10 or 1000 calls, still being O(n), it can easily degrade into consuming minutes. Big-O is overrated as a performance analysis tool

Comment: @aehlke I very much agree that Big-O is overrated, especially since it doesn't account for caching and other hardware variations. And as in your example, it was using up lots of time, so then it's worth optimising. Stack Overflow tends to favour those with less experience, so creating a simple general solution is usually better to post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[xTwisteDx’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63221045/1271826) is correct. Just chain your `replacingOccurrences` calls.

But just a stylistic observation: Frequently, when chaining a bunch of calls like this, we might break it into separate lines, e.g.

```
let newOsetx = osetx
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "11")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "10")
```

When you're doing a bunch of replacements, that can make it a little more easy to read the code at a glance.

---

If you are doing more than two or three replacements, you might consider using some looping pattern. For example, you could use an array of tuples representing the search and replace strings:

```
let replacements = [
    ("e", "11"),
    ("t", "10")
]
```

Then you can loop through them, performing the replacements:

```
var newOsetx = osetx

for (searchString, replacement) in replacements {
    newOsetx = newOsetx.replacingOccurrences(of: searchString, with: replacement)
}
```

Or you can use `reduce`:

```
let newOsetx = replacements.reduce(osetx) { string, replacement in
    string.replacingOccurrences(of: replacement.0, with: replacement.1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob! You and xTwisteDx both had an invalid redeclaration of newOsetx in your examples. Right? First I have to convert the constant to a variable, loop it, and then give it a new name. Which still seems cumbersome to me. But am I inferring correctly that Swift understands the singular "replacement" of the constant you declared, "replacements"? That's kind of fantastic if true.

Comment: No, neither of us had "an invalid redeclaration of newOsetx". If you got that, you simply misunderstood our answers. And yes, the `for` loop requires it to be a variable rather than a constant, but neither the chained approach nor the `reduce` technique require that. Finally, no, Swift doesn't "understand the singular 'replacement' of ... 'replacements'". _I did that,_ not the compiler. I explicitly specified what the iterator variable name was going to be, and as a matter of convention, I always use plural for my array names and singular for my iterator names.

Comment: I think you are looking at xTwisteDx corrected code after I asked him about the typo. He fixed it. I now understand your reduce statement. Thanks for clarifying how you declared the iterator variable name. I thought that would require a previous line to declare it, but now I see it doesn't. That's great, thanks.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Undoubtedly. E.g., you could write a routine to do this in one iteration rather than multiple (but it would still be O(n)). But, as the old quote goes, in 97% of the cases, it would be premature optimization for minimal/negligible gain. Regardless, this would probably be a question better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com, rather than here. I would recommend, though, that before you embark on that, you benchmark in an optimized release build (not playgrounds, not unoptimized debug builds), and make sure that this text replacement is the source of any performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain your method calls. `replacingOccurrences` is a string method that does something to the string, but it returns a string. As a result, you can chain the result of the first and then do the same again. In fact you can do this an indeterminate amount of times, however there are better ways to do it.

```
newOsetx = osetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "ll").replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "10")
```

Another option would be to do it like this.

```
newOsetx = osetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "ll")
let finalOsetX = newOsetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "10")
```

In general have a look at the returned type of a method, it shows up in the drop down window. That returned type will have methods that it can be used with as well.

Comment: newOsetx = newOsetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "10") doesn't work I don't think, but thanks for the initial syntax

Comment: It definitely works, I checked it in playgrounds. Good luck.

Comment: I'm getting "Variable used within its own initial value" error with your latter example.

Comment: @matthewmodine apologies I had a syntax error I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now but it looks like calling the function twice. I'm trying to avoid declaring a new name for the string each time I call the function (pet peeve), so I'm going to opt for other great suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

osetx.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "11").replacingOccurrences(of: "t", with: "10")